# CKEDITOR Define Editable Area

Tags: configuration, ckeditor, wrapper, fckeditor

I'm using CKEDITOR to update the body content of various pages on a website.  While I have applied the existing stylesheets via `config.contentsCss`, I need to wrap the editable area in some HTML like:

```
<div id="contentWrapper">
   <div id="content">
     [EDITABLE CONTENT]
   </div>
</div>
```

Additionally, I need for only [EDITABLE CONTENT] to be written to the CKEDITOR `<textarea>` element and not the wrapper.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: What method are you using to bring the data into the textarea in the first place?

Comment: I haven't figured out how to do that other than adding HTML to the <textarea> before CKEDITOR initializes.

Comment: then I don't understand what the problem is: Do you need the content wrappers inside the editor? If not, then why not just not put them in there?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend putting your page data into a back-end database, then pulling that into your CKeditor instance and making the update to that rather than attempting to parse your page and pull the code in that manner.
If you are worried about the back-end processing hit to pull from the db you can generate cached pages using the database code.